# Issue with Views Contextual Filter using Taxonomy Term Name

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I've run into an issue with views using contextual filters that feels like a bug but usually when I encounter what appears to be a bug it's because I'm doing something wrong so I wanted to see what people here think. My issue is the contextual filter on a taxonomy term name doesn't seem to work when there is another vocabulary in the system that has a couple identical term names. Let me explain further.

I have two different content types (content type A and B) and each is set up with its own taxonomy vocabulary (vocabulary A for content type A and vocabulary B for content type B). Then I've created a view for each content type (view A for content type A and view B for content type B). For each view I'd like to filter its respective content types by taxonomy term name. I've created contextual filters by bringing in the field taxonomy associated with content type and selecting the contextual filter "Name". This works just fine when until the second vocabulary is created in the system.

Now vocabulary A and B have a couple overlapping term names and when I use any of the overlapping term names in the contextual filter nothing is displayed in the view. The contextual filter works if a use any of the other non-overlapping term names. If I delete or rename one of the overlapping term names then it will suddenly work just fine. Also, when I setup the first content type with its vocabulary and view before I'd created the second content type, vocabulary and view it too worked just fine. It's only the presence of another vocabulary that might have a couple identical term names to I have an issue where the contextual filter no longer works.

```
    Vocab A
--------------
    cars
    trucks
    planes

    Vocab B
---------------
    bicycles
    motorcycles
    cars
```

"cars" in this example would be what I mean by overlapping vocabulary term names. They aren't the same terms, different term ids they just have the same label.

I'm using Drupal 8.6.13.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Is it me or is it Drupal?

Thanks!

Comment: try adding a relationship to taxonomy

Comment: I think this has already been answered: see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/201215/90309 + https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/238571/90309