# How to retrieve taxonomy term name in url instead of id in a drupal view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm currently working on Drupal 10 and utilizing Views with filter criteria. However, when I apply filters to my view, it shows the ID of the taxonomy term instead of its name. How can I ensure that it displays the name of the term instead of the ID? Essentially, I want it to show something like 'keys=&theme=operateur' instead of 'keys=&theme=2'.

I tried configuring contextual filters, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Taxonomy term name as contextual filter for view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174251/taxonomy-term-name-as-contextual-filter-for-view)